# Running Pyspark script in VS Code getting error - No module named 'pyspark'

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I am able to run the Pyspark code in Jupyter notebook. but when i tried to run from VS Code I am getting error - No module named 'pyspark'.

Can someone help me here to run from VS Code .

```
from pyspark.sql import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World. Welcome to PySpark")
```

I tried the same code in Jupyter Notebook and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install pyspark module using python package manager.

Open VS Code
In the terminal run the following command

pip install pyspark

pip show pyspark

on VS Code terminal.